# What does these http headers mean?

Tags: http, browser, https, request-headers

```
SEC-FETCH-MODE  navigate
SEC-FETCH-SITE  cross-site
SEC-FETCH-USER  ?1
UPGRADE-INSECURE-REQUESTS 1
```

Especially I would like to know what **SEC-FETCH-USER   ?1** means. Can't understand what the possible values are from here - https://www.w3.org/TR/fetch-metadata/#sec-fetch-user-header

Thanks

Comment: From what I understand so far (still reading on this subject), the `SEC-FETCH-USER` indicates whether the request has been initiated by a user action (ex: submit a form). `?1` means that it was initiated by a user action and `?0` means it wasn't. If sb knows something more, please enlighten us.

Answer (score 1):

### Sec-Fetch-Site

indicates the relationship between

(1) a request initiator's origin and

(2) the origin of the requested resource (server hosting resources)

• same-origin: 1,2 have same scheme,host,port
• same-site: 1,2 have same scheme,domain/sub-domains
• cross-site: if scheme is not same or domain/sub-domain is not same or both
• none

### Sec-Fetch-Mode

Sec-Fetch-Mode indicates the mode of the request so **it has nothing to do with the relation of request-origin & request-resource-destination**
it just focuses on request and the job and it's concern is:
to distinguish between:
• requests originating from a user navigating between HTML pages and
• requests to load images and other resources.
••••••1••••••Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
• if the request wants a resource from another origin
• This is the default value for new requests
• like: requests is getting an external API resources
••••••2••••••Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
• exactly like "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" but more limited than it in 3 things:

1- no JavaScript code can access the response’s properties.
2- If a service worker intercepts this request, it can only modify a limited set of its headers.
3- methods just HEAD,GET,POST/headers just simple headers
• The confusingly named no-cors actually allows cross-origin requests
• like: getting a picture
••••••3••••••Sec-Fetch-Mode: same-origin
if the request wants a resource from it's own origin but that request is not for navigation HTML docs
••••••4••••••Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
The request is initiated by navigation between HTML documents
••••••5••••••Sec-Fetch-Mode: websocket
The request is being made to establish a WebSocket connection

### Sec-Fetch-User

only sent for requests initiated by user activation, and its value will always be ? 1
for example,
assume you want to reach example.com on your browser
the browser will get the main document, page fav icon, a photo and also a script
"the user" wanted main document, so this request will have a "Sec-Fetch-User: ?1"
other requests has not "Sec-Fetch-User" since their requests are not initiated by the user

### Upgrade-Insecure-Requests

sends a signal to the server expressing the client's preference for an encrypted and authenticated response
in other words and in practice:
this header instruct browser to load all subresources on a page over a secure connection
for example if some contents of an https page still loaded over http